# MathML with c# desktop application

Tags: c#, windows, mathml

Hello
I have downloaded the MathML.dll. I am building the mathematical tool in c# window application. I want the functionality like if user inputs as:

```
 sin theta / cos theta = tan theta
```

then that should appear:

```
sin 0   
----- = tan 0  (here 0 = theta)
cos 0
```

on win form.I want to use MathML.dll. but not found any such example. please guide. what steps i have to follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the MathML assembly. Where did you get it from?

**Edit**

It seems that to do what you want, you will have to become comfortable with manually parsing strings. In particular, you might want to take a look at implementing the [Shunting-Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm). I did a quick search for any existing implementations of parsing a math string into MathML, but di not have any luck

Comment: I got it . I have achieved by this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Eq2Img.aspx